# Vue Js - split methods.js in multiple js files in a single vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to split my methods.js in multiple file and import them in my single vue component like this:

```
import script1 from './script1.js'
import script2 from './script2.js'
import script3 from './script3.js'

export default {
  data: {}
  methods: [script1, script2, script3],
  ...
}
```

but it doesn't works.

Is there a way to realize that without use Mixins?

Comment: *How* does it not work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should work:

```js
import script1 from './script1.js'
import script2 from './script2.js'
import script3 from './script3.js'

export default {
  methods: { script1, script2, script3 }
}
```

Note the `[]` has been changed to `{}`.

This assumes that your script files are using default exports for the functions.

However...

Writing `methods: { script1, script2, script3 }` is an ES6 shorthand for:

```js
methods: {
  script1: script1,
  script2: script2,
  script3: script3
}
```

So what you'll end up with is 3 methods called `script1`, `script2` and `script3`.

The naming problem here is easily solved, you just need to use an appropriate name  when you do the import. Something like:

```
import getUserStatus from './script1.js'

export default {
  methods: {
    getUserStatus
  }
}
```

Doing it this way it wouldn't matter what the function is called inside `script1.js`, the choice of name is yours to make when you import it.

To use default exports within `script1.js` it would be something like this:

```js
export default function (/* function args here */) {
  // ...
}
```

This creates an anonymous function. You could choose to give it a name if you like.

There are two potential problems with this approach:

1. You can only import one function from each file.
2. The name is chosen when you import the function. This could lead to duplication and possible errors if other code requires a particular name.

One solution to these problems would be to use named exports instead of a default export. So within `script1.js` it might look something like:

```js
export function getUserStatus (/* function args here */) {
  // ...
}

export function getUserGroup (/* function args here */) {
  // ...
}
```

You'd then import these using:

```js
import { getUserStatus, getUserGroup } from './script1.js'

export default {
  methods: {
    getUserStatus,
    getUserGroup
  }
}
```

This works fine if you want the importer to cherry-pick which functions to include. However, if each file exports multiple functions that need to all be included together using exactly the right names you could do this instead:

```js
export default {
  getUserStatus (/* function args here */) {
    // ...
  },

  getUserGroup (/* function args here */) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

This is using a default export again but this time we're exporting an object containing two functions as properties. We could then use this in our component as:

```js
import script1 from './script1.js'

export default {
  methods: {
    ...script1
  }
}
```

Here the spread operator is being used to copy the properties of `script1` across to the `methods` configuration object. The names of the methods will match the names of the properties within the exported object. The identifier `script1` used to hold the imported object doesn't have any impact on the method names in this case.

However, if you find yourself in this scenario, trying to import several interlinked methods, you may find it better to go with a mixin as it seems likely you'll need more than just methods anyway.

Reference for the different forms of `export`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export

Answer (score 1):

You are close, you need to import methods from within each file, not the whole file;

```
import { script1 } from './script1.js'
import { script2 } from './script2.js'
import { script3 } from './script3.js'

export default {
  data: {}
  methods: { script1, script2, script3 },
  ...
}
```

And for example, in script1.js:

```
export const script1 = function(x) {
   console.log(x);
};
```